# Can Openpyxl be used to create ErrorBars w/ dynamically updating heights?

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018934/openpyxl-chart-error-bar-styles) showed how to set error bar heights to fixed values which are set within python.   Is it possible to set instead to set error bar heights to calculated values stored by excel in other cells?   Ideally, such that changing the underlying data could change the errror bar heights?

For that matter, is that even possible for excel to do?

Here's my attempt:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.data_source import NumDataSource, NumData, NumVal, NumRef
from openpyxl.chart.series import ErrorBars
from openpyxl.chart.series_factory import SeriesFactory
from random import randint

# Create a new workbook
book = Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet = book.active

# Write 5 random ints to worksheet
for i in range (1,6):
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=1,value=randint(1,100))


# write formula to computer Average  
sheet.cell(row=6,column=1,value='=AVERAGE(A1:A5)')                

# write formula to compute StdDev
sheet.cell(row=7,column=1,value='=_xlfn.STDEV.S(A1:A4)/10')

# create a chart with single bar whose height is the Average As Calculated by Excel
chart = BarChart()
barheight = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=6, max_col=1, max_row=6)
series = SeriesFactory(barheight)

# This creates an error bar of static height 5  
myNumVals = [NumVal(0, None, v=5)]    
myNumData = NumData(pt=myNumVals)
myNumDataSource = NumDataSource(numLit=myNumData)

# This seems like something that might work, but it doesn't work.  
# myNumDataSource = NumDataSource(NumRef("A7"))
myErrorBars=ErrorBars(plus=myNumDataSource,minus=myNumDataSource,errDir='y',errValType='cust')
series.errBars = myErrorBars

chart.series.append(series)
sheet.add_chart(chart, "A9")
book.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Probably. What have you tried? Can you provide some simple code that attempts what you have in mind?

Comment: I edited it above to include my attempt.  
I can successfully create a static error bar using NumLit, but can't figure out how an ErrorBar using NumRef

Comment: I think this solved it: 

`myNumDataSource = NumDataSource(NumRef(Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=7, max_col=1, max_row=7)))`

Comment: I think the solution is to do what you appear to have done: reverse engineer the structure from an existing file. How error bars work is not documented in the specification, just the relevant tags. Would be great if you could submit a PR to the documentation with this example.