# Openpyxl Bar graph Error bars

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, errorbar

I was wondering if it is possible to set an error bar series to a reference. What I would like to do is reference cells with the error values already calculated. and then have it displayed on top of the bar graphs.

I found a similar question where they have seemed to do a version of what I am trying, but when I edit their example I get an error. 
Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**Example of what I want the graph and error bars to look like**
[image]
**Error:**

TypeError: expected class 'openpyxl.chart.error_bar.ErrorBars'

**similar Question**
[openpyxl chart error bar styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018934/openpyxl-chart-error-bar-styles)

**My Current Code**

```
            chart1 = BarChart()
            chart1.type = "col"
            chart1.height = 10
            chart1.width = col + 7
            chart1.title = name

            data = Reference(ws, min_col=4, min_row=23, max_col=17)
            cats = Reference(ws, min_col=4, min_row=29, max_col = 17)
            eBars = Reference(ws, min_col=4, min_row=26, max_col=17)

            s= Series(data)

            series = SeriesFactory(data, title="y direction error")
            series.errBars = eBars

            chart1.append(s)
            chart1.append(series)
            chart1.legend = None
            chart1.set_categories(cats)

            chart1.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"
            #chart1.x_axis.tickLblSkip = 0

            chart1.shape = 10
            ws.add_chart(chart1, "C3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... setting a reference to the plus and minus

I see your point, replace `numLit`with `numRef`:

> [NumDataSource / NumRef](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.chart.data_source.html?highlight=NumDataSource)
>
> ```
> class openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumDataSource(numRef=None, numLit=None)  
>     `numLit`  Values must be of type <class ‘openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumData’>
>     `numRef` Values must be of type <class ‘openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumRef’>
> ```

```
eBarsNumDataSource = NumDataSource(NumRef(eBars))
series.errBars = ErrorBars(errDir='y', errValType='cust', plus=eBarsNumDataSource, minus=eBarsNumDataSource)
```

---

> **Question**: TypeError: expected class 'openpyxl.chart.error_bar.ErrorBars'

Your `eBars` is of Type `Reference` but you need Type `openpyxl.chart.error_bar.ErrorBars`.

> [class openpyxl.chart.error_bar.ErrorBars](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.chart.error_bar.html?highlight=ErrorBar)
>
> ```
> class openpyxl.chart.error_bar.ErrorBars(
>     errDir=None, 
>     errBarType='both', 
>     errValType='fixedVal', 
>     noEndCap=None, plus=None, minus=None, val=None, spPr=None, extLst=None)
> ```

You need at least the following Parameters:

```
 ErrorBars(errDir=Value must be one of {‘x’, ‘y’}, 
           plus=Values must be of type <class ‘openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumDataSource’>, 
           minus=Values must be of type <class ‘openpyxl.chart.data_source.NumDataSource’>, 
          )
```

Follow `def list2errorbars(...` in the linked similar Question.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Am I wrong or do I need the error values for the `def list2errorbars(...`  function to work? The way these sheet work is excel does all the calculations and then the graph and error bars are all referenced. is there any way to set it up like that? Right now it appears that the bars how to be calculated a head of time vs referenced and setting a reference to the `plus` and `minus`. Thank you again for your reply!!

Comment: That worked out great!! Thank you so much for the help and the awesome explanation!